# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression when checking for NULL

Tags: java, sql, ms-access

This the SQL query I intend to use in my code and it generates the `missing operator` error.

Where is the error?
`Segment_ID` is supposed to contain numbers so is it valid to use `NULL` here?

```
 rs=st.executeQuery("select Metrics.Metric_Name "
     + "from  Metrics INNER JOIN Report ON Metrics.Report_ID=Report.Report_ID "
     + "where Report.Report_Name  like '%"+s+"%' and Metrics.Segment_ID==null "  );
```

Answer (score 0):

That must be:

`rs=st.executeQuery("select Metrics.Metric_Name "
            + "from  Metrics INNER JOIN Report ON Metrics.Report_ID=Report.Report_ID "
            + "where Report.Report_Name  like '%"+s+"%' and IsNull (Metrics.Segment_ID) "  );`

The check if null use `is null` not `== null`

Comment: And after doing what you suggested, it gives an error [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1.

Comment: @user3608233 I have edit my post. Try it again please.

Comment: @user3608233 can you remove `and IsNull (Metrics.Segment_ID)` from your statement and try it again, so that you can see if it is this part of the statement which not works?

Comment: Oh yes ! It does work if i exclude "and Metrics.Segment_ID IS NULL" from the query. now Metrics.Segment_ID contains numbers so is it valid to use NULL or should we use ' ' instead ?

Comment: @user3608233 Is the column nullable?

Comment: oh yes ! it has blank entries as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54501/discussion-between-jens-and-user3608233).

Answer (score 0):

Youy can try this:-

```
"select Metrics.Metric_Name "
+ "from  Metrics INNER JOIN Report ON Metrics.Report_ID=Report.Report_ID "
+ "where Report.Report_Name  like '%"+s+"%' and Metrics.Segment_ID IS NULL";
```

Comment: :still gives the error  [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1.

Comment: Try to execute this query seperately on Access. and see is it right or not. If it's correct then try to correct your code.

Answer (score 0):

Change `==` to `=` or `IS NULL`. There is no operator as `==` in SQL comparison operators.

As a note : Your code is subject to SQL injection. Please use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) API

Comment: On doing this, it gives the error  [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1.

Comment: You are missing to set a parameter in the query before you execute.

Comment: `Too few parameters. Expected 1` denotes that you haven't set the required parameters for the query before execution. It expects 1 parameter.